# windows cmd script ran but no output file saved as expected

Tags: windows, script, automation, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-task-scheduler

I have a simple `test.cmd` script which contains one line:

```
echo test > log.txt
```

If I right click the script file and `Run as Administrator`, it runs fine and a log.txt file is saved in the folder.

However, when I created a task in Task Scheduler which triggers this script on a specific time, there is no `log.txt` saved even though everything seemed to have worked - I can see the Last Run Result as `"The operation completed successfully"`. I tried to click the Run button in the Task Scheduler to run this task as well, and the same thing, no `log.txt` is generated.

How can I make this scheduled task work? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Did you configure an appropriate directory in the task scheduler? That is where the output will go ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably running in a different working directory. In the `edit action` box, where you set the cmd to run, change the "start in" box and add the directory you expect the output to be.

Comment: Oh I see. The `log.txt` is found in Windows\System32 folder. Coming from a Linux background and I found this very confusing, haha. Thank you @BlueDrink9 and @DavidPostill.